# Choosing a jQuery Tooltip Plugin - main considerations?

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

What are the key considerations I should take if I need a tooltip plugin that will allow me the most basic use (simple pop box with a little "triangle" pointing towards the hovered element)?

I saw Qtip2 is supposed to support IE6+ while Jquery UI supports IE8+ so that's one consideration I guess, but what else?

I saw [this comparison](http://bseth99.github.io/projects/jquery-ui/9-tooltip-comparison.html), the author talks about setting the title "from code" vs "static". Not sure I understand the terminology and the actual consequences that this difference will lead to?

Also, Are any of the 4 tools mentioned in that comparison are especially light or heavy? and shall I simply take the least code I need and run if from my own server, or use the full code, on the creator's CDN?

Comment: _"the most basic use (simple pop box with a little "triangle" pointing towards the hovered element)?"_ Use `title` attribute

Comment: Well I do want to have it inside a shadowed box, and I want the box to have a "trianglish" tip pointing towards the element. and have option to color it or control size of box.

Comment: This should be possible using `css` `:hover` , `:after` , see https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: is there a full demo then anywhere? when I searched I only saw CSS3 example, which aren't compatible with older browsers.

Comment: What is not compatible with older browsers ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: See post , utilized `css` `:hover` , `:after`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `css` `:hover` , `:after`

```css
div:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: blue;
  color: gold;
  left: 60px;
  padding:4px;
  position: absolute;
}

div:hover #triangle-left {
  display:block;
}

#triangle-left {
  top: 15px;
  left:50px;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div data-tooltip="abc"><span>hover</span><span id="triangle-left"></span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried playing with this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8wajmont/) but capabilites seem limited, problem with postitiong, and also the tip itself doesn't have any border/shadow...

Comment: @rockyraw See original Question at _"if I need a tooltip plugin that will allow me the most basic use"_ . Yes, may require additional fine-tuning. Trianlge does have `box-shadow` though shadow is at box of element , not angle of triangle